# How to trigger another event when clicking a link in rails 3.1?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This question may be raised many time here. I would like to trigger another event when clicking a link on rails view. Something like:

```
<%= link_to 'Referesh', event, :onclick => 'another_event' %>
```

I have another_event as a ruby method called url_handler with two params index and url. Can I do something like below?

```
<%= link_to 'Customer', customers_path, :onclick => '/url_handler?index=1&url=user_menus_path' %>
```

Or if not, how to implement this trigger?

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean to use `link_to` with the `:remote => true` flag set because the `:onclick` option is expecting JavaScript that will be inlined into the resulting HTML.

You must also have a route to that method to be triggered defined in `routes.rb` or Rails will not know how to call that action.

Example:

```
<%= link_to('Refresh', another_event_path, :remote => true) %>
```

Comment: Received error:undefined method `stringify_keys' for "/url_handler?index=1&url=user_menus_path":String. The code is <% link_to 'Customer', customers_path, "/url_handler?index=1&url=user_menus_path", :remote => true %>. I just modified the post to emphasize the another event. Thanks.

Comment: You can only trigger one action per click unless you have some kind of JavaScript helper that does the rest for you. If you need that, I'd suggest structuring this to be a jQuery + UJS (Unobtrusive JavaScript) type link. Always read the documentation on the method in question. The way you're using it is just plain wrong.

Comment: JS seems to be the only way in rails to accomplish this. Is there online articles about this topic? thanks.

Comment: You might want to start [here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) and then read the documentation.